# Elasticsearch - How to use multiple analyzers in a query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to implement **Synonym** and **Stopword** Filters in my query. For that I created two analyzers and both are working fine individually. But I want to use them both, how can I?

```
GET my_index/_search/
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "_all": {
             "query": "Good and Bad",
             "analyzer": [
                 "stop_analyzer",
                 "synonym"
             ]
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The above query throws me an error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [analyzer]",
            "line": 6,
            "col": 26
         }
      ],
      "type": "parsing_exception",
      "reason": "[match] unknown token [START_ARRAY] after [analyzer]",
      "line": 6,
      "col": 26
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

I think I can't use an array or an object there as when I use single analyzer like `"analyzer": "stop_analyzer"` or `"analyzer": "synonym"` it works great. So my question is how can I use both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html), which can combine those two simple analyzers into one complex.

#### Defining custom analyzer

Let's suppose you have created the index in the following way:

```
PUT my_index
{  
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "stopwordsSynonym": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "my_synonym",
              "english_stop"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "english_stop": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": "_english_"
          },
          "my_synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "nice => good",
              "poor => bad"  
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "my_text": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "stopwordsSynonym"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And added a record:

```
POST my_index/my_type
{
    "my_text": "People aren’t born good or bad. Maybe they’re born with tendencies either way, but it’s the way you live your life that matters."
}
```

Now by default the search on `my_text` will use the `stopwordsSynonym` analyzer. This query will match the document because `nice` is a synonym of `good`:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "my_text": "nice and ugly"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Testing a custom analyzer

You can also test your analyzer like this:

```
GET my_index/_analyze 
{
  "analyzer": "stopwordsSynonym", 
  "text":     "nice or ugly"
}

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "good",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "SYNONYM",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "ugly",
         "start_offset": 8,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

Compare this with `standard` analyzer output:

```
GET my_index/_analyze 
{
  "analyzer": "standard", 
  "text":     "nice or ugly"
}

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "nice",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 4,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 0
      },
      {
         "token": "or",
         "start_offset": 5,
         "end_offset": 7,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "ugly",
         "start_offset": 8,
         "end_offset": 12,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

In fact, `stopwordsSynonym` replaced `nice` token with `good` (and its `type` is `SYNONYM`), and removed `or` from the list of tokens since it is a common English stopword.

#### Defining analyzer for a query

In order to use a different analyzer for a given query one may use [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "my_text:nice and poor",
            "analyzer": "stopwordsSynonym"
        }
    }
}
```

Or [`match_phrase`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "my_standard_text" : {
                "query" : "nice and poor",
                "analyzer": "stopwordsSynonym"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In any case `analyzer` should be added to the settings of the index at creation time (see the beginning of the answer).

Take a look also at [search analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html), which allows to use different analyzer for searches.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @userpk Sure, updated the answer. Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.